# How to get Sum of total price of products available in Recycle Adapter and pass to another fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I want to get Total price from recycle adapter items, but i cant get from it.
This is my code of adapter,

```
public class CartHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView cartUPDTPrice,cartPRICE,cartDESC,cartTITLE;
            ImageView cartIV,removeIMG,minusIMG,plusIMG;

        public CartHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cartUPDTPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartUPDTPrice);
            cartPRICE = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartPRICE);
            cartDESC = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartDESC);
            cartTITLE = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartTITLE);
            cartIV=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartIV);
            removeIMG=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.removeIMG);
            minusIMG=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.minusIMG);
            plusIMG=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.plusIMG);
        }
    }


    public void onBindViewHolder(final CartAdapter.CartHolder holder, int position) {
        prodCART = cartPRO.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        holder.cartUPDTPrice.setText(prodCART.getPPrice().trim());
        holder.cartPRICE.setText(prodCART.getPName().trim());
        holder.cartDESC.setText(prodCART.getPName().trim());
        holder.cartTITLE.setText(prodCART.getPName().trim());
        holder.removeIMG.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure,You wanted to Remove\n"+holder.cartTITLE.getText());
                    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                             cartPRO.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                             notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                }catch (Exception e){
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Now i want the SUM of cartPRICE of all items present in adapter and pass to fragment that display Grand total of cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take one public  static int like `int sum = 0` and add vales in that int every time your adapter called like `sum = sum + prodCART.getPPrice();` and use that int anywhere you want .

```
public static boolean add= true;
```

in your onBindViewHolder();

```
if(add){
 sum = sum + prodCART.getPPrice();
 add= false; }
```

Comment: i tried, but every time i scroll value adds and give wrong total.

Comment: use one Boolean after adding first time value set false .

Comment: can u give more explanation how to to do this?

Comment: use like this . 
Boolean add = true;

Comment: suppose i have 18 products in cart, and when i add their prices to some int only first 10 items price is add.remaining value not added, why?

Comment: It because of there are only 10 items display on screen

Comment: any solution to that?, I need total price when adapter fills. if user did not scroll then real price is not shown.

Comment: you can use like this
 int price= recyclerview.getcount;
for(int i=0; i<price; i++){
int sum = 0;
int sum = sum + cartPRO.get(i).getPPrice() ;

}

Comment: I got some problem when i use i<count, it gives 0 always.

Comment: use count = recyclerview.getChildCount();

Comment: Thanks for your help, i use adapter.getItemCount() and i got right Answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Create the customListenerAction to get the control in fragment 

public interface CartActionListener{
void RemoveCardClicked(ArrayList<prodCART> remainingCartList);
}

pass the interface method in the RecycleAdapter Constructor 

public class CartHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView cartUPDTPrice,cartPRICE,cartDESC,cartTITLE;
            ImageView cartIV,removeIMG,minusIMG,plusIMG;
     CartActionListener cartActionListener

        public CartHolder(View itemView  ) {
            super(itemView);
this.CartActionListener  =cartActionListener ;
            cartUPDTPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartUPDTPrice);
            cartPRICE = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartPRICE);
            cartDESC = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartDESC);
            cartTITLE = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartTITLE);
            cartIV=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartIV);
            removeIMG=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.removeIMG);
            minusIMG=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.minusIMG);
            plusIMG=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.plusIMG);
        }
    }


    public void onBindViewHolder(final CartAdapter.CartHolder holder, int position) {
        prodCART = cartPRO.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        holder.cartUPDTPrice.setText(prodCART.getPPrice().trim());
        holder.cartPRICE.setText(prodCART.getPName().trim());
        holder.cartDESC.setText(prodCART.getPName().trim());
        holder.cartTITLE.setText(prodCART.getPName().trim());
        holder.removeIMG.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure,You wanted to Remove\n"+holder.cartTITLE.getText());
                    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                             cartPRO.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                             notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                             CartActionListener.RemoveCardClicked(cartPRO);
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                }catch (Exception e){
                }
            }
        });

    }


while creating the instance for the recycle Adapter pass the interface method


new YourRecycleAdapter(this,cartPRO,new CartActionListener(){
public void RemoveCardClicked(ArrayList<prodCART> remainingCartList){
   //it will return your remaining updated list of prod cart 
  //based on the remaining cart list to do your calculation and update it in your fragment since you are adapter instance in fragment screen

});

i guess it will work fine for you . Based on your code you may need some more changes on your code
```

Comment: But how to show sum of product prices at a time when  adapter fill and recycle view populated?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use in Your main activity as

```
int count  = recyclerview.getcount;
and then you do like 
for(int i=0; i<count.getsize; i++){
int sum = 0;
int sum = cartPRO.get(i).getPPrice(); + sum;

}
```

and use this sum as total counting..

Comment: recyclerview.getcount is not availabel, getCHildcount is available.

Comment: Not recycler view i mean its object